# OpenID Connect with multiple clients and SSO

Tags: sharepoint, single-sign-on, openid, openid-connect

I am creating this post after doing quite a lot of research on OpenID Connect myself including reading the specs and the more I read the more questions come up. I hope that someone is able to help me and clear my confusion.
The OpenID Connect specs are good but only contain very basic examples that do not match my usecase. Please let me try to explain my situation and then ask my question:

I try to use OIDC in conjuction with **SharePoint Online** and two applications. One is a **webservice** (back-end) that is supposed to interact with SharePoint and the other one is a simple **single page application** (front-end) running in the browser of the user that allows him to interact with the webservice. My IdentityProvider is **Active Directory**. The task of the webservice is to do some actions in user context on SharePoint but it is also supposed to allow the user to execute a limited set of actions that only an administrator of SharePoint would be allowed to do (e.g. I want to allow the user to create a SiteCollection but not delete it) For that reason I managed to register the webservice with SharePoint so that it receives a Special access_token which grants it admin access in SharePoint.

My thoughts so far:
1) If the user logs into SharePoint he receives an id_token and an access_token from the AD. He can use the id_token to log to SharePoint and interact with it directly. (I got this working)
2) I also want to authenticate the user in the front-end single page application because some users should not be able to make certain calls to the webservice and I want to hide these buttons from them in my application. For that I could use the id_token from step 1).
3) If my webservice should do something in the context of a user I can just pass the access_token that was created for that given user in step 1) to the webservice and then forward it to SharePoint.
4) If my webservice should execute a privileged function that the user is not allowed to do on his own, I want to use the Special access_token that the webservice already pocesses to make the call. In that case I have to authenticate the user at my webservice with his id_token from step 1) to make sure that I want to allow this request of his.

My question:
Does every client have to make a request for his own id/access_token? (These different flows are described in the OIDC and OAuth specs [here](https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect) and [here](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/which-oauth-flow-to-use)) and will this still be Single-Sign-On?
Or can I just generate a single id_token and access_token for a user in step 1) and then pass these on to all clients that need them?

Thank you very much in advance!!